# How to change the current username in SetaPDF Merger Api

Tags: php, pdf

I'm using the SetaPDF Merger API - and I need to find a way to change the current username in the file links.

For Example:

In the '$filename =' link below I need the  to change to the current username with each new user.That way each user can view their unique documents only.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

$filename = '/home/drssem5/public_html/modassistance.info/wp-content/uploads/user_uploads//f4506t.pdf';

```
// Add the filename
$merger->addFile($filename);
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say `username` do you mean `drssem5` in this example?

Answer (score 0):

I find that this solution worked in Wordpress:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$subscriber = $current_user->display_name;
$username = $subscriber;
 } 

 //Add $username to your link
 $filename = '/home/drssem5/public_html/modassistance.info/wp-           
 content/uploads/user_uploads/' .$username. '/f4506t.pdf';
```

Have fun,
Cbfreeman